# Node.js error const power = 10 ** precision generates unexpected token

Tags: node.js, npm, token

node --version
v6.10.1

sample run

```
$ node ds180List.js
/home/pi/repos/monitor/node_modules/round-to/index.js:21
        const power = 10 ** precision;
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Node.js source code:

```
    const sensor = require('ds18b20-raspi');
    var listOfDeviceIds = sensor.list();
```

Should just get the DS180 sensors

Comment: Node 6 is very out of date at this point. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation suggests you'll need at least v7, but see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/ for current support.

Comment: You're using a very outdated version of node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `**` (Exponentiation) operator in Node.js v6. Use `Math.pow()` instead:

```js
const power = Math.pow(10, precision);
```

or update to a newer version of Node.js (at least v7 but recommended v14)

Comment: agree, OP should update to the current LTS (14), but version 7 is where the Exponentiation operator was added.

Comment: Thank you, I was in a situation supporting some 3+ year code that they didnt want to update. I was pretty sure it was the older version, but you gave me confirmation. I updated to version 8 only because some of their libraries will not work with latest (according to the owner). Again, THANKS!